# Laravel binding not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the laravel service container today for the first time. I know there is a lot to find on the internet about it but I can't find a solution for it. I'm trying to bind an interface to a class but when I do this I receive the error:

> Target [App\contracts\UploadService] is not instantiable.

This is my service container called UploadServiceContainer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class UploadServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\UploadService', 'App\Classes\upload\upload');
    }
```

}

I try to instantiate it like this in my controller:

```
public function storeTicket(makeTicketRequest $request,UploadService $upload)
{ }
```

I've registered my Serviceprovider in app.php. And I've also done:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: Are you sure that your class name is upload in lower case?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, but I know I should follow psr-2 :)

Comment: and when u inject class directly is it working?

Comment: Are you registering this service provider in your `config/app.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `bind()`, you're using `App\Contracts\UploadService` (capital "Contracts"), but the error message states `App\contracts\UploadService` (lower "contracts"). Correct the discrepancy and it should work.